# How prevent page rerendered on <apex:actionFunction>?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm using `<apex:actionFunction>` and my page is reloaded. I don't use `reRender` attribute and I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent page reloading.

Maybe there is a special value to set to `reRender` ?

**EDIT :**

Here is my code :

```
  <apex:page controller="myController">
      <apex:commandButton value="save" onclick="save()"/>

      <script type="text/javascript">

          function save(){
              // Some code
              myMethod('param');
              // Some code
          }  

      </script>
      <apex:form >
          <apex:messages />
          <apex:actionFunction name="myMethod" action="{!controllerMethod}">       
              <apex:param name="param" value="" />
          </apex:actionFunction>  
      </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

And my controller :

```
 public String controllerMethod() {
     String values = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param');
     system.debug('Values : ' + values);

     return values;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you call the action function just put `return false;` to the end of the call:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="myFunction" action="{!someMethod}" /> 

<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Click me</a>
```

Or based on your code:

```
<apex:commandButton value="save" onclick="save(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: I tried your tip but it doesn't work. I post some code.

Comment: That's what I do but my page still reload !

Comment: This didn't work for me. Its still reloading

Answer (score 4):

What should work in most cases is to just add `reRender=""`, or as Neo suggests `rerender="none"`. It doesn't really matter what is put between the `""` as long as it doesn't match the name of any elements on the page.

The way the `<actionFunction>` tag works is that if there is no `reRender` attribute defined it refreshes the entire page, but if there is a `reRender` attribute it only refreshes the elements defined in the tag. So adding `reRender=""` will lead to nothing being re-rendered, whereas `reRender="none"` or `reRender="false"` will re-render the element whose id is `none` or `false`, respectively.

`Visualforce` doesn't strictly enforce that the ids specified in your `reRender` exist on the page. As a result if that id doesn't exist, it will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

In this tag:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="myMethod" action="{!controllerMethod}">
```

Add `reRender="false"` so it ends up being:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="myMethod" action="{!controllerMethod} reRender="false">
```

This worked for me!

Comment: It also works to use reRender="none"

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work for me and according to [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) this is not what the `reRender` attribute is for.

Comment: This didn't work for me as well. I guess there are no false/true values for rerender. It just picks up for checking the component id and then proceeds with the rerendering.